# Kendo MVC: Dropdown in Grid Column

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, grid, dropdown

im trying to populate a grid in an asp.net mvc app.
i have an issue with one specific column in the grid which needs to render as dropdown list.

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)
  .Name("gridExclusions")
  .AutoBind(false)
  .Columns(columns =>
  {
    columns.ForeignKey(c => c.SubTaskId, GetSubTasks(item.Id), "Value", "Text").Width(100).Title("Sub Task").Filterable( ftb => ftb.Multi(true) .Search(true));
    columns.Command(command => { command.Edit(); }).Width(100);
   })
```

....

Because every item in the grid can have different list of sub task, my question is how to pass the current item id "item.Id" to the function GetSubTasks(int id)

Answer (score 0):

try using the kendo escape characters - # in a string like => "#{parameterNameInModel}"